# C# - Find and replace specific string in file

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2019

wise community!
I ask you for help again in my, maybe simple, situation.

So.
I have some file (.ini-file) with some text lines. Example of file:

```
[SomeGuy]
Name = Alex;
Surname = Newbie;
EMails = "-mails=@mail1@somemail.com;@mail2@somemail.com;" -MainEmail=mail1@somemail.com
Visits = 0;
...
```

I'm trying to find a solution to:
1) Replace:

```
EMails = "-mails=@mail1@somemail.com;@mail2@somemail.com;" -MainEmail=mail1@somemail.com
```

to

```
EMails = "-mails=@mail1@somemail.com;@mail2@somemail.com;" -MainEmail=NewEmail
```

2) Or delete:

```
EMails = "-mails=@mail1@somemail.com;@mail2@somemail.com;" -MainEmail=mail1@somemail.com
```

and fit in its place:

```
EMails = "-mails=@mail1@somemail.com;@mail2@somemail.com;" -MainEmail=NewEmail
```

Where 'NewEmail' - is a new variable value taken from user's input.

I searched here for some solutions, found some and applied applied in this example:

```
string IniFile = @"S:\My.ini";
    var fileStrings = File.ReadAllLines(IniFile).ToList();

    for (var i = fileStrings.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (fileStrings[i].StartsWith("EMails"))
        fileStrings.RemoveAt(i);
    }

string NewEmail = "EMails = \"-mails=@mail1@somemail.com;@mail2@somemail.com;\" -MainEmail"+EMailField.Text;
File.AppendText(IniFile).Write(NewEmail);
File.WriteAllLines(IniFile, fileStrings);
```

EMailField is users input field, from which I take written value (EMailField.Text).

In this example I get error after input:
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'S:\My.ini' because it is being used by another process.

But it is not open, used or smth else.
I also try to write all line from original file to another by applying this:

```
string NewIniFile = @"S:\MyNew.ini";
...
File.WriteAllLines(NewIniFile, fileStrings);
```

But again get same error - "...'S:\My.ini' is being used by another process".

Using Visual Studio 2019 and creating Windows Forms application.

Please poke me in the eye what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The code looks good to me, the only problem seems to be file access. Do you have permissions to read the file - can you open it in explorer without windows asking for admin priviledges?

Comment: File used it s not a sign that the file is open but may be used by another windows service or task and also may be you don't have access to modify the file

Comment: `File.AppendText()` opens a file AND KEEPS IT OPEN. You need to store the return value in a variable and close it after you've written to it (preferably via `using`). Otherwise, it will remain open until the garbage collector runs, which - as you have discovered - is *after* you tried to use it in `File.WriteAllLines()`. In the duplicate question, pay attention to the "Please note a common error we see very often on StackOverflow" part!

Comment: Matthew, thanks for involve!. I solve it just by:
fileStrings.RemoveAt(3);
fileStrings.Insert(3,NewString);
because EMails is always on 3rd line :D

Comment: @Auditive I would not suggest relying on line order, Ini files usually do not require that. Finding the correct line is easy enough